# Docker container doesn't load in VPS (Debian) which does work locally

Tags: docker, nginx

I've developed an application that uses four Docker containers (php7.0-fpm, nginx, mysql and phpmyadmin) which used to run like it should both locally (MacOS) and on my VPS (Debian 9 Stretch). Yesterday i've added port 80 to my nginx config in my docker-compose file to make sure nginx can force http traffic to https. This works locally like i expected, but when i pulled the changes on my VPS i get the following message when i run `docker-compose up --build`:

> ERROR: for my_nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint my_nginx
>   (ff89cec0a968850919eebabe9e003c0bd4e65205eb6f3c3dd286037b3a1745fc):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: listen: address
>   already in use
>
> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint my_nginx
>   (ff89cec0a968850919eebabe9e003c0bd4e65205eb6f3c3dd286037b3a1745fc):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: listen: address
>   already in use

The strange thing is that when i run the command locally everything works fine.

Below the contents of my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2.0"

services:
     nginx:
          build: ./nginx/
          ports:
               - 443:443
               - 80:80
          volumes:
               - ${APPLICATION_ROOT}:/${WEBROOT}
               - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
               - ./nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          restart: always
          depends_on:
               - php
          environment:
               ENVIRONMENT: "${APPLICATION_ENV}"
               URL: "${APPLICATION_URL}"
          container_name: my_nginx

     php:
          build: ./php/
          ports:
               - 8080:80
          volumes:
               - ${APPLICATION_ROOT}:/${WEBROOT}
          restart: always
          depends_on:
               - mysql
          environment:
               ENVIRONMENT: "${APPLICATION_ENV}"
               URL: "${APPLICATION_URL}"
               MYSQL_HOST: "${DB_HOST}"
               MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
               MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
               MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
          container_name: my_php

     mysql:
          build: ./mysql/
          volumes:
               - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
          restart: always
          ports:
               - 3306:3306
          environment:
               MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
               MYSQL_HOST: "${DB_HOST}"
               MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
               MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
               MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
               explicit_defaults_for_timestamp: 1
          container_name: my_db

     phpmyadmin:
          build: ./phpmyadmin/
          restart: always
          depends_on:
               - mysql
          ports:
               - 8181:80
          environment:
               PMA_HOST: my_db
               MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
               MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
               MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
          container_name: my_phpmyadmin
```

Does anybody know what i'm missing here? I've tried changing the php ports to `8282:80`, but that didn't work either (and i don't really understand how ports & all work). And how come it does work locally on my mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, if you read it, says it all:

> address already in use

Something is already listening on port `80`. If you run `netstat -pln | grep 80`, it will show which process exactly is blocking your port. You may then `kill -9` it and build your containers with no error.

Comment: Apache is installed on my vps and listens to port 80 so i made nginx listen to port 8001. That solved it. Thnx